# Multiple datatypes in a 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to code a program that simulates a zookeeper taking temperatures of animals. I was given a .txt file which has the name of animals and their "normal" temperatures. My instruction is to code a 2D array to hold these known values into the program. Here's what I did:

```
  // The NormalValues method holds the known normal values of the animals at the zoo in a 2D array.
private string NormalValues(object[,] iArray)
{
    object[,] values =
    {
        {"Zebra", 129.5},
        {"Unicorn", 54.9},
        {"Platypus", 12.19},
        {"Dragon", 999.98},
        {"Elephant", 103.66},
        {"Manticore", .035},
        {"Duck", 1.34},
        {"Basilisk", 45.2},
        {"Sphinx", 8.00},
        {"Tiger", 3.21}
    };

    return values.ToString();
}
```

Later in the code, I need to choose a file and import a bunch of data into a list and then loop through the imported list and display lower than normal and higher than normal values...

How do I use the 2D array mentioned before to hold those values when I need to loop through the imported list?

Blockquote

Comment: Your 2D array already holds all the values it needs to, so your question makes no sense. The instructions you posted specify that you need to compare the data in the list you read to the data in the array. That's what you should do.

Comment: One of the main reasons that beginners have trouble writing code is that they don't actually know what the code is supposed to do. They try to jump straight from an idea of the final result to the code to produce that result with no understanding of the steps to get there. You need to spend time to develop that understanding first. Work out what the logic is first, then write code to implement that logic explicitly. How would you do it if it was a purely manual process? That will tell you the steps you need to perform. Formalise that into an algorithm then implement that algorithm in code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a `Dictionary<string, double>`:

```
var NormalValues = new Dictionary<string, double> {
    {"Zebra", 129.5},
    {"Unicorn", 54.9},
    {"Platypus", 12.19},
    {"Dragon", 999.98},
    {"Elephant", 103.66},
    {"Manticore", .035},
    {"Duck", 1.34},
    {"Basilisk", 45.2},
    {"Sphinx", 8.00},
    {"Tiger", 3.21} 
};
```

Later in the program, you look up the correct temperature by animal name.

If you have a file consisting of lines with comma-separated values, such that the first value is the animal name, the second value is the animal ID (in case you have several of the same kind of animal), and the third value is the temperature reading, you could do this:

```
var temps = File.ReadLines("some file").
      Select(line => line.Split(","));


foreach(var temp in temps)
{
    // temp[0] is the animal name, and temp[2] is the temperature
    var normal = NormalTemps[temp[0]];
    var recorded = Double.Parse(temp[2]);
    var diff = normal - recorded;

    // do something with the diff
    if (Math.Abs(diff) > 0.5)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Oh no! {temp[0]} with ID {temp[1]} has a temperature off by {diff} degrees!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is obviously a homework question, the instructions specifying a 2D array would likely mean that using a `Dictionary<K,V>` is out. While structurally it may appear as a 2D array, it removes all of the challenge that is intended by specifying a 2D array.